# Filename from label to textfield

Tags: java, label, textfield

I have this:

```
 private void jOpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
   fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    fc.setApproveButtonText("Open");
    fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    if (fc.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File dr = fc.getSelectedFile();
        if(!dr.isFile()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Isn't file","eroare",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }else if(!dr.canRead() || !dr.canExecute()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"You dont't have privileges","eroare",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }else{
            FileFilter filtruJPG = new FileFilter(){
                @Override
                public boolean accept(File file) {
                    return file.getName().endsWith("jpg");
                }

            };
            File[] fisiere = dr.listFiles(filtruJPG);
            if(fisiere.length==0){
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Doesn't contain photos","eroare",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                poze = Arrays.asList(fisiere);
                jLabel.setText("");
                afisare();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wanna extract filenames of photos into textfield from a label, but when I open a photo it isn't show on label.
If I choose DIRECTORIES_ONLY it's working, but i get the filename of folder on textfield,

Answer (score 0):

Try to add file.getAbsolutePath() to the JFileChooser.

```
  File dr = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: Maybe you found a solution. You already tried to comment out, the line with FILES_ONLY ?